# How to configure System Restore to restore "everything"?

Tags: windows-7, system-restore, volume-shadow-copy

Given that I can browse a restore point and see the deleted files, how to restore this point completely? When I try to, Windows says everything's fine, but the files I was looking for weren't restored (`D:\1\willbedeleted.txt`) and the files created after the restore point didn't vanish (`D:\1\createdafter.txt`).

I never used this feature before and I thought that setting "Restore system settings *and previous versions of files*" would do the thing.

Also, after restore and reboot there's a message box saying "your documents have not been affected". But I wanted them to be affected! I don't care if files created after creating the point are deleted or overwritten.

Is there a way to do what I want?

**Update:**

I tried `vshadow -revert={SnapID}` on Windows 7 (see [Windows VSS/vshadow](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=ru&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.it-kb.ru%2F2016%2F09%2F01%2Fwindows-vss-volume-shadow-copy-service-and-vshadow-cli-tool-from-adk-as-protection-from-crypto-ransomware%2F&edit-text=)), but it fails with: `ShouldBlockRevert() ... Not implemented`. I hope someone tries that on a later version of Windows. Possible solution for Windows 7 can be rebuilding vshadow from sources and handling the error in `ShouldBlockRevert()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, no.

The `Restore Previous Versions` capability that allows you to recover an earlier version of your personal files works separately from a `System Restore`. Although they both rely upon the `Volume Shadow Copy` service and are configured in the `System Protection` interface, dropping back to a previous `System Restore` point only affects the operating system itself and the installed applications.

Here is a good article that elaborates a bit more on the `Restore Previous Versions` process:

[Use Windows 7’s Previous Versions to Go Back in Time and Save Your Files](http://www.howtogeek.com/56891/use-windows-7s-previous-versions-to-go-back-in-time-and-save-your-files/)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be under the impression that System Restore backs up files in, for example, your user's Documents directory. This is not the case. It only saves copies of system files (such as drivers and registry files). To create a backup of personal documents there is a built-in backup utility in Windows or several third-party options that backup files either locally or to the cloud.

Comment: Why are you saying that it doesn't backup files? I tell you, I can browse the restore point and view the deleted files

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't back up files. I am saying it only backs up system files, not personal files.

Comment: Is `D:\1\willbedeleted.txt` a system file? I'm "under impression" that the most useful feature was there, but was disabled by M$

Comment: How are you browsing the restore point?

Comment: Volume shadow copy, on which System Restore is based since Windows Vista, make snapshot of entire volume (including user files).

Comment: @Darren right click a drive, "properties"/"previous versions". Choose and open

Comment: But you are using System Restore to restore the system yes? That only restores the system by definition.

Comment: @basin, please see my comment above.  Both the `System Restore` function and the `Restore Previous Versions` function are fueled by the `Volume Shadow Copy` service and configured within the `System Protection` interface.  However, a `System Restore` will only restore a snapshot of the operating system itself, not your personal files and folders.  The article that I referenced above provides a good explanation, also.